# (in R) How to incorporate dose response IC50 values, from dr4pl models into a ggplot2 curve?

Tags: r, ggplot2, drc

I was helped on this site in combining the `dr4pl` (the replacement for '''`drc`''') 4 parameter logistic dose response model with ggplot. It works really well, but I'm looking to incorporate the the IC50 for each curve into the plots, AND to output a table with the values as well.
Example data:

```
    #load packages
    library(ggplot2)
    library(data.table)
    library(dr4pl)
    library(car)
    
    #example data
curve = c("C1","C1","C1","C1","C1","C1","C1","C1","C1","C2","C2","C2","C2","C2","C2","C2","C2","C2","C3","C3","C3","C3","C3","C3","C3","C3","C3")
POC =c(1.07129314, 0.91126280, 0.97914297, 0.95904437,0.88509670, 0.84338263, 0.75843762, 0.61319681, 0.52635571, 0.84563087,1.24435113, 1.11757648, 0.82383523, 0.82763447, 0.72585483, 0.31953609, 0.15056989,  0.10057988, 0.57384256, 0.65984339, 0.81439758, 0.84572057, 0.62797088,  0.30800934, 0.08957274,
       0.06360764, 0.04451161)
dose = c(0.078125,0.156250, 0.312500,0.625000,1.250000,2.500000, 5.000000,10.000000,20.000000,0.078125,0.156250,0.312500,0.625000,  
         1.250000,2.500000,5.000000,10.000000,20.000000,0.078125,
         0.156250,0.312500,0.625000,1.250000,2.500000,5.000000,10.000000,
         20.000000)
example2<-data.frame(POC, dose, curve)

#this code will write  model that can be incorporated into 
predict.dr4pl <- function (object, newdata=NULL, se.fit=FALSE, level, interval) {
  xseq <- if (is.null(newdata)) object$data$Dose else newdata$x
  pred <- MeanResponse(xseq, object$parameters)
  if (!se.fit) {
    return(pred)
  }
  qq <- qnorm((1+level)/2)
  se <- sapply(xseq,
               function(x) car::deltaMethod(object, 
                                            "UpperLimit + (LowerLimit - UpperLimit)/(1 + (x/IC50)^Slope)")[["Estimate"]])
  return(list(fit=data.frame(fit=pred,lwr=pred-qq*se,
                             upr=pred+qq*se), se.fit=se))
}

#ggplot the example
ggplot(example2, aes(dose,POC, col=curve))+ 
  geom_point(size=4, shape=1) +
  geom_smooth(method="dr4pl",se=F)+ 
  coord_trans(x="log10")+
  theme_bw()+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(lineheight = 0.9, face="bold", size=20, hjust=0.5))+
  ggtitle("Dose Response")+
  theme(axis.title = element_text(face="bold", size = 14))+
  theme(axis.text = element_text(face="bold", size = 12, colour="black"))
```

the above will generate a plot with three curves, each with a fitted 4pl model. I need the IC50 to show up in the plot, or in a table elsewhere so I can put it into the plot myself.

Grateful in advance for any help.

Edit June 2021:

new data set to help with debugging the script provided:

```
new_data<-structure(list(cell_line = c("MCF7", "MCF7", "MCF7", "MCF7", 
                                       "MCF7", "MCF7", "MCF7", "MCF7", "MCF7", "MCF7", "MCF7-A", "MCF7-A", 
                                       "MCF7-A", "MCF7-A", "MCF7-A", "MCF7-A", "MCF7-A", "MCF7-A", "MCF7-A", 
                                       "MCF7-A", "T47D", "T47D", "T47D", "T47D", "T47D", "T47D", "T47D", 
                                       "T47D", "T47D", "T47D", "T47D-A", "T47D-A", "T47D-A", "T47D-A", 
                                       "T47D-A", "T47D-A", "T47D-A", "T47D-A", "T47D-A", "T47D-A", "T47D-pR", 
                                       "T47D-pR", "T47D-pR", "T47D-pR", "T47D-pR", "T47D-pR", "T47D-pR", 
                                       "T47D-pR", "T47D-pR", "T47D-pR"), compound = c("Drug A", 
                                                                                      "Drug A", "Drug A", "Drug A", "Drug A", 
                                                                                      "Drug A", "Drug A", "Drug A", "Drug A", 
                                                                                      "Drug A", "Drug A", "Drug A", "Drug A", 
                                                                                      "Drug A", "Drug A", "Drug A", "Drug A", 
                                                                                      "Drug A", "Drug A", "Drug A", "Drug A", 
                                                                                      "Drug A", "Drug A", "Drug A", "Drug A", 
                                                                                      "Drug A", "Drug A", "Drug A", "Drug A", 
                                                                                      "Drug A", "Drug A", "Drug A", "Drug A", 
                                                                                      "Drug A", "Drug A", "Drug A", "Drug A", 
                                                                                      "Drug A", "Drug A", "Drug A", "Drug A", 
                                                                                      "Drug A", "Drug A", "Drug A", "Drug A", 
                                                                                      "Drug A", "Drug A", "Drug A", "Drug A", 
                                                                                      "Drug A"), dose = c(0.01, 0.078125, 0.15625, 0.3125, 0.625, 
                                                                                                                1.25, 2.5, 5, 10, 20, 0.01, 0.078125, 0.15625, 0.3125, 0.625, 
                                                                                                                1.25, 2.5, 5, 10, 20, 0.01, 0.078125, 0.15625, 0.3125, 0.625, 
                                                                                                                1.25, 2.5, 5, 10, 20, 0.01, 0.078125, 0.15625, 0.3125, 0.625, 
                                                                                                                1.25, 2.5, 5, 10, 20, 0.01, 0.078125, 0.15625, 0.3125, 0.625, 
                                                                                                                1.25, 2.5, 5, 10, 20), parental = c("MCF7", "MCF7", "MCF7", "MCF7", 
                                                                                                                                                    "MCF7", "MCF7", "MCF7", "MCF7", "MCF7", "MCF7", "MCF7", "MCF7", 
                                                                                                                                                    "MCF7", "MCF7", "MCF7", "MCF7", "MCF7", "MCF7", "MCF7", "MCF7", 
                                                                                                                                                    "T47D", "T47D", "T47D", "T47D", "T47D", "T47D", "T47D", "T47D", 
                                                                                                                                                    "T47D", "T47D", "T47D", "T47D", "T47D", "T47D", "T47D", "T47D", 
                                                                                                                                                    "T47D", "T47D", "T47D", "T47D", "T47D", "T47D", "T47D", "T47D", 
                                                                                                                                                    "T47D", "T47D", "T47D", "T47D", "T47D", "T47D"), medPOC = c(1.00934409313115, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.956036980819649, 0.954030667407294, 0.711853180626466, 0.241538799146477, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.0567749571032392, 0.0155968806238752, 0.00581957552880206, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.00378717257100532, 0.0059174440467226, 0.945368038063252, 0.929888217437452, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.835779167562444, 0.586348465064098, 0.262177612337144, 0.0824082662867902, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.0308960382876894, 0.00894423842501589, 0.0061419835150226, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.00374687836102447, 0.964364310824993, 0.95414565025418, 1.00205847809834, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.973855651871399, 0.876721635476499, 0.782657842062487, 0.485817405545171, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.240963289831941, 0.0807368351333095, 0.0218556352405241, 0.988828883403082, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                1.12687653176236, 1.14174538911381, 1.09793468012842, 0.9371711107187, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.683580746738641, 0.349521000688784, 0.153807969259144, 0.0557784035696989, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.00951109986306135, 0.945736502721647, 1.03384512851939, 1.13359282933971, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                1.02798863227664, 0.731271070765377, 0.394548651675076, 0.139037002094163, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.0594879837491901, 0.0233289720871743, 0.00163350004591345), 
                         sd = c(0.0487946611701357, 0.0652579737057601, 0.0447000542436252, 
                                0.0761742909565082, 0.0271364685090581, 0.0157757699801731, 
                                0.00457291598057361, 0.00618036276893572, 0.0031691999231949, 
                                0.00189564811623345, 0.0286788195412834, 0.0726775067251048, 
                                0.0598425497920862, 0.11240260462323, 0.0876844650331781, 
                                0.016269001522037, 0.00768323265792931, 0.0027283359541071, 
                                0.00530943514487439, 0.00340553154613564, 0.0513524691501586, 
                                0.0984457469912835, 0.0451143466008112, 0.0818218693028968, 
                                0.0934768958498176, 0.0540191453047165, 0.0608084812187634, 
                                0.0238245870875823, 0.011089245968621, 0.00995992003975256, 
                                0.0717550694254788, 0.0510188619416171, 0.0901696938469758, 
                                0.100897280181198, 0.0426100049631484, 0.0403803080203038, 
                                0.0383100464040449, 0.0383778124586436, 0.0153293502919647, 
                                0.0108310224482204, 0.110583411728824, 0.0714281429520549, 
                                0.127292213170872, 0.121050868088146, 0.15773243775593, 0.144314150863785, 
                                0.0584119879286731, 0.0179382293021653, 0.0142390344682626, 
                                0.0148403765582003), dose1000 = c(10, 78.125, 156.25, 312.5, 
                                                                  625, 1250, 2500, 5000, 10000, 20000, 10, 78.125, 156.25, 
                                                                  312.5, 625, 1250, 2500, 5000, 10000, 20000, 10, 78.125, 156.25, 
                                                                  312.5, 625, 1250, 2500, 5000, 10000, 20000, 10, 78.125, 156.25, 
                                                                  312.5, 625, 1250, 2500, 5000, 10000, 20000, 10, 78.125, 156.25, 
                                                                  312.5, 625, 1250, 2500, 5000, 10000, 20000)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                              -50L), groups = structure(list(cell_line = c("MCF7", "MCF7", 
                                                                                                                                                                           "MCF7", "MCF7", "MCF7", "MCF7", "MCF7", "MCF7", "MCF7", "MCF7", 
                                                                                                                                                                           "MCF7-A", "MCF7-A", "MCF7-A", "MCF7-A", "MCF7-A", "MCF7-A", "MCF7-A", 
                                                                                                                                                                           "MCF7-A", "MCF7-A", "MCF7-A", "T47D", "T47D", "T47D", "T47D", 
                                                                                                                                                                           "T47D", "T47D", "T47D", "T47D", "T47D", "T47D", "T47D-A", "T47D-A", 
                                                                                                                                                                           "T47D-A", "T47D-A", "T47D-A", "T47D-A", "T47D-A", "T47D-A", "T47D-A", 
                                                                                                                                                                           "T47D-A", "T47D-pR", "T47D-pR", "T47D-pR", "T47D-pR", "T47D-pR", 
                                                                                                                                                                           "T47D-pR", "T47D-pR", "T47D-pR", "T47D-pR", "T47D-pR"), compound = c("Drug A", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                "Drug A", "Drug A", "Drug A", "Drug A", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                "Drug A", "Drug A", "Drug A", "Drug A", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                "Drug A", "Drug A", "Drug A", "Drug A", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                "Drug A", "Drug A", "Drug A", "Drug A", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                "Drug A", "Drug A", "Drug A", "Drug A", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                "Drug A", "Drug A", "Drug A", "Drug A", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                "Drug A", "Drug A", "Drug A", "Drug A", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                "Drug A", "Drug A", "Drug A", "Drug A", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                "Drug A", "Drug A", "Drug A", "Drug A", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                "Drug A", "Drug A", "Drug A", "Drug A", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                "Drug A", "Drug A", "Drug A", "Drug A", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                "Drug A", "Drug A", "Drug A", "Drug A", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                "Drug A"), dose = c(0.01, 0.078125, 0.15625, 0.3125, 0.625, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          1.25, 2.5, 5, 10, 20, 0.01, 0.078125, 0.15625, 0.3125, 0.625, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          1.25, 2.5, 5, 10, 20, 0.01, 0.078125, 0.15625, 0.3125, 0.625, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          1.25, 2.5, 5, 10, 20, 0.01, 0.078125, 0.15625, 0.3125, 0.625, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          1.25, 2.5, 5, 10, 20, 0.01, 0.078125, 0.15625, 0.3125, 0.625, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          1.25, 2.5, 5, 10, 20), .rows = structure(list(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `dr4pl` doesn't handle multiple dose responses as the `drc` package does via the `curveid` parameter.

My solution would be to extract the IC50s using `dr4pl::IC()` and then add them as vertical lines to the plot.

Here's a function that extracts and saves IC50 as a `data.frame`:

```
library(data.table)
library(dr4pl)

multiIC <- function(data, 
                    colDose, colResp, colID, 
                    inhib.percent, 
                    ...) {
  
  # Get curve IDs
  locID <- unique(data[[colID]])
  
  # Prepare a vector to store IC50s
  locIC <- rep(NA, length(locID))
  
  # Calculate IC50 separately for every curve
  for (ii in seq_along(locID)) {
    # Subset a single dose response
    locSub <- data[get(colID) == locID[[ii]], ]
    
    # Calculate IC50
    locIC[[ii]] <- dr4pl::IC(
      dr4pl::dr4pl(dose = locSub[[colDose]], 
                   response = locSub[[colResp]],
                   ...), 
      inhib.percent)
  }
  
  return(data.frame(id = locID,
                    x = locIC))
}
```

The input data should be a `data.table`. Use the code as follows:

```
dfIC50 <- multiIC(data = example2, 
                  colDose = "dose", 
                  colResp = "POC", 
                  colID = "curve", 
                  inhib.percent = 50)
```

To obtain:

```
> dfIC50
  id         x
1 C1 29.065593
2 C2  3.269516
3 C3  2.186479
```

Then add this line to your ggplot:

```
geom_vline(data = dfIC50, 
           aes(xintercept = x, 
               color = id))
```

Comment: Hi mattek, thanks for your answer. It worked initially. However, when I tried on another dataset I get the following error  Error in get(colID) == locID[[ii]] : 
  comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types
or:
Error in dr4pl.default(dose = locSub[[colDose]], response = locSub[[colResp]],  : 
  The same numbers of dose and response values should be supplied. 
it seems to vary. And when I regenerated the above example2 data with dput, and put into a new session, I got the first error message again. Seems like a bug, any ideas how to solve?

Comment: Would you be able to share that other dataset?

Comment: Hi Mattek, thanks again. I'm aware the rules here are quite strict, and I've fallen foul of the mods before. How is the best way to upload that dataset? Shall I edit the original question and post it at the bottom?

Comment: How about posting a link to an online resource, e.g. your dropbox or google drive folder, here? Or, if the dataset isn't too large, just edit the question and add another set at the bottom.

Comment: I have posted another dataset, would be very grateful of you could take a look.

Comment: Hi, is anyone able to help with this?

Comment: The provided code works fine with the new dataset. Just convert it to a `data.table`, i.e. `library(data.table)` and then `new_data = data.table(new_data)`

Comment: Hi Mattek, yes, this works, thank you. Could you take a look at another question? Some of the data in a larger set is causing problems and I'm trying to dissect it out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68275012/why-is-my-data-generating-argument-is-of-length-zero-in-dr4pl-dose-response